# Is it better to use one big script instead of multiple smaller ones?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, web-crawler

I'm learning web crawling with python. I have a CSV file with a lot of URLs. Using python 2.7 and selenium I'm currently crawling these websites to extract data like: *body width (in pixels), HTTP response, page load speed* and `meta name="viewport"` tag.

The results of the script I then export to a CSV file with each column containing the type of data extracted (see below). I'm planning to extract many more types of data by writing new crawlers.

How my current script exports the data to the CSV file -> CSV file looks like this:

```
Website      |     body width  | HTTP response  |  load speed (in secs)  | Viewport 
www.url1.com |       690       |         200    |           2            |      No   
www.url2.com |       370       |         404    |           0.5          |      Yes
```

However, my script (one single .py file) is getting longer, thus a little more complex, due to more code lines by each new function added. I worry that the more functions i add to it, the slower and more error sensitive it will get. How I see it, I right now have two options:

**Option 1. Keep writing new crawling functions to the existing script file**

**Option 2. Writing new crawling functions to different script files:** I'm thinking about, from now on, to write new crawlers on separate .py files (1 crawler = 1 .py file) and also to split my current script (one single .py file) into multiple crawlers (multiple .py files).

I then can run each crawler separately and write the results of all crawlers into one single CSV file (like illustrated above). By using multiple crawler files, (assumption), I think I'll have cleaner, less error sensitive, faster and more flexible crawlers, in comparison to having all crawlers in one .py file like I have now.

So my questions:

1. What are the pros and cons of option 1 & 2?
2. Is one option better than the other, if so why?
3. Is my assumption in option 2 correct?

Excuse me if my post may not be specific enough, but getting my questions answered will help me tremendously!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean code is good. I would look to put common functions into something like a `crawler_library.py`, and then have your specific scripts import functions that they need from there.

With regards to your assumption, it isn't *axiomatically* true - code in different scripts is no functionally different to code in one script. Realistically, though, it is *generally* true. It's easier to maintain and improve, and for most people, putting code into functions allows them to modularise what they are trying to do, makes it easier to understand, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if by "better" you mean tidier, cleaner code. Then yes, It will be a lot tidier. If you have other web crawling projects, not just this one, importing them as modules is also great, it means they are reusable, and decoupled. Being able to seamlessly switch modules in and out is a good thing.